# Красная точка в пункте меню "Запоздалые ответы"

Tags: обсуждение, очередь-проверок

Что это за красная точка в меню? Что она означает?

Вообще я никогда не захожу в очередь проверок по запоздалым ответам, но красная точка периодически появляется. Если зайти, то говорит, что очередь проверка пуста.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]